# How to run Shell script from HTML?

Tags: 12.04, scripts

I'm somewhat new to Ubuntu Linux.

I need to run the shell script from a `html` code. As I read somewhere like using `Apache2` to generate a `html` and somehow I've succeeded to run a `sh` file from html, but I'm unable to see the command prompt which executes the commands in the sh script. It's running may be as a daemon.

So can any body help me how to make it visible?

Answer (score 4):

This is a totally wrong approach. The HTML file does nothing, it is a Markup language, that instructs a browser how to show you different elements. What you need it is a PHP, ASP, CGI, etc script that uses the system's shell to run arbitrary commands.

Comment: thanks for the reply Frantique.. i've used 'CGI' only for this.... but unable to view the output... is there any way we can make the terminal visible..?

Answer (score 1):

When you run a shell script as CGI, which is what I believe you are doing (or trying to do), it is run from the apache or other web server daemon and its output isn't visible anywhere. You can redirect its output to a file, for example by replacing the original script with one that runs the script and saves the output:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
./original.sh | tee --append file-to-save-to
```

(You should probably also update your question to show what your objective is, in addition to the problem you have encountered.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply otus, my intention is to make some build system with graphical user interface... rather than typing commands to build some code(ex: like make  xxxx etc.) i want to create HTML buttons to be clicked for building appropriate module. But by using CGI i'm unable to see the output for 'make'   and even i'm unable to know whether it is running background or not.... so any one can help me regarding this.. is there any simple approach to follow other that what i'm using... thanks in advance

Comment: outus,
i've tried as u said to catch the output to some file, but the output is getting stored in the file only when every thing goes correct, if some error has occured (in the command mentioned in original.sh) then the file looks empty...:-(

Comment: suresh, errors are written to stderr, so you'll need to redirect that to either a different file or the same: e.g. `./original.sh 2>&1 | tee --append file`

Answer (score 0):

You can use perl-cgi do this. Take a look at

- **[Net::SSH](http://search.cpan.org/~ivan/Net-SSH-0.09/SSH.pm)**
- **[Net::Telnet](http://search.cpan.org/~jrogers/Net-Telnet-3.03/lib/Net/Telnet.pm)**
- **[Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~turnstep/Net-SSH-Perl-1.34/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm)**

perl Packages. These modules will help you to make client connections.

Sample script using **Net::telnet**

```
use Net::Telnet ();
$t = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 10,
                      Prompt => '/bash\$ $/');
$t->open("sparky");
$t->login($username, $passwd);
@lines = $t->cmd("who");
print @lines;
```

You can render the output of this program using cgi and display it in browser.

But the limitation of this would be like you cannot use a interactive shell to run your command.